# Facebook opengraph actions with multiple objects

Tags: facebook, tags, facebook-opengraph

How can one achieve 
User listening to {SONG_TITLE} by {ARTIST_NAME}

Answer (score 2):

start here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/bridge/

**Facebook Music bridge**

*Goal*:
Enable play buttons on feed stories on Facebook.com that can play and pause tracks and indicate which is playing.

*Mechanism*:

The client loads part of the Facebook JS SDK which provides an interface for FB to send play and pause commands to the client, and allows the client to send status updates back to Facebook.